# C# Integer Values and String Values of json to print color cell

Tags: c#

I'm trying to apply thresholds to the data I get in certain columns to set the background color of the field to one color if it exceeds one value and another color if it exceeds another value.
Until everything is fine.

Now, in the example that I show you, I am treating the AUXREASON column that delivers time value, that is, receiving values such as :30 or 1:31. These values correspond to the time that is in auxreasonmode.

Well, since I'm a bit of a nob here I've gotten stuck because when I put a value in the textBox, for example, if it exceeds :30 it turns yellow. Well, it doesn't work because it's not an integer value by having the character:

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
{
    int umbral2 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    int umbral3 = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
    int umbral4 = int.Parse(textBox6.Text);
    int v = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["ESTADO"].Value);
    int v2 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["AUXREASON"].Value);

    if (v >= umbral2)
    {
        row.Cells["ESTADO"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    if (v < umbral2)
    {
        row.Cells["ESTADO"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    if (v2 > umbral3)
    {
        row.Cells["AUXREASON"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    if (v2 > umbral4)
    {
        row.Cells["AUXREASON"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    if (v2 < umbral3)
    {
        row.Cells["AUXREASON"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can parse it to a TimeSpan, then you can use the TotalSeconds for comparison.

Comment: you may want to use some `else`s there: if .. else if ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat your timespans as what they are and use their total seconds to compare:

```cs
TimeSpan estado = TimeSpan.ParseExact(row.Cells["ESTADO"].Value, @"m\:ss", null);
TimeSpan auxreason = TimeSpan.ParseExact(row.Cells["AUXREASON"].Value, @"m\:ss", null);

if (estado.TotalSeconds >= umbral2)
// ...
```

See [TimeSpan.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact?view=net-7.0#system-timespan-parseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider))

... or even better, protect yourself against invalid data by using [TimeSpan.TryParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider, TimeSpan)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparseexact?view=net-7.0#system-timespan-tryparseexact(system-string-system-string-system-iformatprovider-system-timespan@))

```cs
TimeSpan estado;

if(!TimeSpan.TryParseExact(row.Cells["ESTADO"].Value, @"m\:ss", null, out estado))
{
    // if parsing fails, you can assign a fallback value here
    estado = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // default: 1 second
}
```

To address different formats, provide an array of format pictures you consider valid:

```cs
TimeSpan estado;
string[] formats = new string[] { @"m\:ss", @"\:ss" };

if(!TimeSpan.TryParseExact(row.Cells["ESTADO"].Value, formats, null, out estado))
{
    // if parsing fails, you can assign a fallback value here
    estado = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // default: 1 second
}
```

Comment: Hello: but a have a problem with linea TimeSpan auxreaxon.TimeSpan auxreason = TimeSpan.ParseExact(row.Cells["AUXREASON"].Value, @"m\:ss", null); System.FormatException: 'The input string is not in the correct format.'

Comment: In that case you may need an array of format strings to cater for your different values (minutes:seconds and seconds only). See [ParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact?view=net-7.0#system-timespan-parseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider)).

Comment: Hello friend, Ok it work for me, thank for all info and for your time